# How to combine group of local commits to single push in IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, push, commit

In IDEA I am trying to push some commits.

I have a requirement that on remote server it looks like single action.

I click to push and see following window
[image]

I expected to see squash checkbox here but don't see it.

Please help me.

Comment: Cannot give IDEA advice, but squashing is part of an interactive rebase or a merge, not a commit. Try looking there.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can do it using rebase. Go to *VCS/Git/Rebase*. Then select *Interactive* option. It will show you a list of commits, where you can pick which ones you want to squash.

After you hit *Start rebasing* it will prompt you for a commit message for the squashed commit. After that is done you can push your squashed commit using push dialog.

[image: Squash dialog]

More information about rebase in IntelliJ is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/interactive-rebase.html).

Comment: it may also be helpful to read this  [Git Tools - Rewriting History article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to know what to enter into the "Onto field" of the "Rebase branch" dialogue: e..g `HEAD~3` can be used to select the last 3 commits.

Comment: Hmm, there's one dialog before that, this will tell you to use `HEAD~2` notation to work with last two commits.  That worked like a charm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018704/intellij-how-to-squash-local-branch-only

Comment: Thanks, this is the easiest approach still working with Intellij Idea 2019.1

Comment: Dont forget to "force push"

Answer (score 43):

There is a new way:

Version Control -> Log -> Right click on the commit -> `Interactively rebase from here` and then you can choose to pick/squash the rest of commits.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is no way to select "Squash" for multiple commits and it gets tedious to do it one by one.

Comment: @DmitrySerdiuk you can shift click to select the commits you want to squash and then right click -> select squash.

Answer (score 25):

For me, the simplest way with IntelliJ is:

- Go to `Log` tab and choose the commit from which you want to squash
- Right click and select `Reset Branch to this commit`
- Choose the `Soft Or Mixin` options to keep your changes from the commit
- Commit your changes and don't forget to check the `Amend commit` option

Comment: This is indeed the simplest way and I find it to be the least stressful and error prone.

Comment: I suggest that on step 3 it would be better to choose a `Soft` option instead of `Mixed` to have all changes already staged for commit.

Comment: The only first step was enough for me.

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version of IntelliJ you can simply select all the commits, right-click -> `Squash commits`

Comment: What are the potential dangers of doing this? This seems deceivingly easy. What does IntelliJ do under the hood?