# Intellij "before commit" options meaning

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-squash

I cannot find the documentation about the several options (checkboxes) that are visible when commiting.

[image: commit options]

I'm looking for an option to `squash` all commits from the IDE, and I'm wondering if one of these options couldn't help me to do that. Is there any official documentation about the different options?

Comment: Not sure about squashing but those options activate/deactivate some code-inspections tasks which are described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/commit-changes-dialog.html) - scroll down to *Before Submit / Before Commit*. Perhaps the [*Rebasing Commits Dialog*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rebasing-commits-dialog.html) from the idea docs will be of some help regarding the squash option.

Comment: I don't think you can squash commits using these actions. There is other way to do it from IntelliJ though. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26904021/1291150

Comment: Thanks, both answers are quite useful, I found what I was looking for. @Morfic If you write an answer I'll accept it. (since your answer is what the question is about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the brief descriptions of the before commit operations ([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-dialog.html)):

| Operation | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Reformat code | Perform code formatting according to the Project Code Style settings. |
| Rearrange code | Rearrange your code according to the arrangement rules preferences. |
| Optimize imports | Remove redundant import statements. |
| Perform code analysis | Perform code analysis Run code inspection on the files you are about to commit/shelve. |
| Check TODO (filter name) | Review the TODO items matching the specified filter. Click Configure to choose an existing TODO filter, or open the TODO settings page and define a new filter to be applied. |
| Cleanup | Automatically apply the current inspection profile to the files you are going to commit/shelve. |
| Update copyright | Add or update a copyright notice according to the selected copyright profile - scope combination. |

Answer (score 1):

Following my original comment, I think there are 2 distinct features:

1. The before commit section, described in detail [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-dialog.html), offers a few code-inspections tasks which Idea will run on your classes before actually committing them. Depending on their output (eg: new TODOs), some may request a confirmation that you indeed want to perform the commit:

[image: before commit options]

2. The `squash` feature, which I'm not very familiar with yet, is perhaps accessible from the [*Rebasing Commits Dialog*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rebasing-commits-dialog.html)

Comment: There is no description of the before commit actions in the links you provided. Maybe they have moved it. It's a lot better if you copy/paste the answer so it stays here. Content on the link can change, link can die etc