# How can I correct an incorrect Change-Id when pushing to Gerrit?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gerrit

I push to Gerrit, and my code is reviewed such that valid comments are made. I make the changes, and do a fresh commit and push, assuming that I’ve created a new patch set.

However, I forget to tick the ‘Amend commit’ box in IntelliJ:

[image]

This means that the new commit gets pushed to Gerrit with a new Change-Id, and so the change does not become associated with the previous push. Now my reviewers can’t (easily) make the connection between the 2 changes, nor can anyone who looks at this in the future.

My commit messages are multi-line, and so cannot easily be altered on the command line if I wanted to do a `git amend`.

My approach has been to try and undo the ‘bad’ commit --- but I end up getting confused in Git Hell.

I end up:

1. checking out origin/master into a new repo on my laptop and
   manually making  my changes again (yes, really), then
2. deactivating the commit-msg hook in my .git/hooks directory, then
3. making a commit with the desired Change-Id manually added to the message, then
4. pushing to Gerrit.
5. Finally I re-activate the commit-msg hook

This can’t be the best way to do it. It works, but it can’t be the best way to do it.

What do?

Comment: Why multi-line commit messages cannot easily be changed on the command line? You only need to execute "git commit --amend", what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **squash** the two last commit into one, keeping in the message the initial Change-ID. The squash allow you to combine different commits into one. It takes place into interactive **rebase** process. The explanation to do it [using command line.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)

You could use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26898511/2394026) to do using interface.